# Contradiction of Bulk's Modulus and Pressure exerted by a static liquid

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, elasticity, stress-strain

My question is about a scenario where a certain amount of air is passed through water. Now,  this air will form a bubble and due to the buoyant force acting on it, it will rise.
We know that the pressure exerted by a liquid at a certain distance 'h' from the free surface is ρgh where ρ is the density of the liquid. By this formula, we can predict that our bubble will increase in volume. Because when it rises , the pressure exerted on the bubble decreases, thus allowing it to increase in volume.

Now, we know that Bulk's modulus of elasticity = Volume stress / Volume strain. Volume stress, in our case, will be ΔP, where ΔP is the difference between the total pressure exerted on the bubble and the pressure exerted by the bubble. Volume strain will be -(ΔV)/V.
∴Bulk's Modulus of Elasticity = ΔP* V/-(ΔV)

Rearranging we get, ΔV = -ΔP* V/Bulk's Modulus of Elasticity

So even if  the bubble rises and ΔP decreases,  ΔV will always be negative and therefore the volume of the air bubble will keep decreasing.

Comment: The vapor inside a bubble is an ideal gas.  The bulk modulus of an ideal gas is 1/P.  So PV=cnst, and, as P decreases, V increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Volume stress, in our case, will be ΔP

You've confused the pressure $P$ with a pressure difference $\Delta P$.

As the bubble rises, the pressure decreases; thus, $dP=\rho g\,dh<0$. (Confirm for yourself that $dh$ is negative because we're subtracting a larger depth from a smaller depth.) Then, from the definition of the bulk modulus $K$,

$$dV=-V\frac{dP}{K},$$

with $K>0$ and $V>0$, we must have $dV>0$, which matches our intuition that the volume increases with ascent. I see no contradiction.

Comment: In my question, I clearly wrote that " ΔP is the difference between the total pressure exerted on the bubble and the pressure exerted by the bubble."

Comment: Are you referring to the [Laplace pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_pressure)? Please clarify.

Comment: In any case, I edited my question  to avoid the possibility that we’re using $\Delta P$ in two different  contexts.